# Selenium and GWT problems

Tags: gwt, selenium, webdriver

I successfully created a Selenium test that goes on a page and check 2/3 things.

"Run as JUnit test" is working perfectly, showing the page and testing some GUI elements ( connecting to the GWT hosted mode at URL : `http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`)

However if I try to use maven test task "mvn test", the IE window shows the "Development Mode requires the Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin" ...

I've seen that there may be workaround with FF where you can add plugins directly using Webdriver code. But I find nothing for IE(7).

Any help appreciated thanks !